# AJAX on click not calling/loading as it should

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have been learning AJAX for the best part of 2 hours, trying to get my head around how to get this to work, it seems it is calling the function as if I put an alert in, it all works fine.

I tried using another method and it seemed to call the function on it's own and it would load what the .php page is echoing.

What am I doing wrong in order for it to not work at all?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('a.fire').click(call_ajax);
function call_ajax() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://127.0.0.1/onlineshop/admin/scripts/test.php",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html){
            $("#holder").append(html);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Edit: I have also just tried

```
$('a.fire').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://127.0.0.1/onlineshop/admin/scripts/test.php",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(html){
                $("#holder").append(html);
            }
        });
});
```

Which also does not work.

EDIT: I have now got code that GET's the php file I wanted, but for some reason does it on it's own

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function call_ajax() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://127.0.0.1/onlineshop/admin/scripts/test.php",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html){
            $("#holder").append(html);
        }
    });
}
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {

$(document).ready(function() {
$('a.fire').click(call_ajax());
    });
});
```

The issue with this code is that it fires on it's own

EDIT: Now have new code, that is attempting to fire according to Firebug console but I get the alert ERROR: error, so I don't have a clue what is happening in order for it to fail, I have also tried many different URL's with no working solution

```
$('a.fire').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/onlineshop/admin/scripts/test.php",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html){
            $("#holder").append(html);
        },
        error:function(xhr, text, error){
            alert("Error: " + text);
        }
    });
});
```

SOLVED: I have now got it to work! For some reason my anchor had a href of "", which would cause it to reload the page and removing my GET from the page

Comment: What's the question / problem?

Comment: im confused, is your ajax request firing when `call_ajax` is invoked?

Comment: Add an error callback and display any errors.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, the problem is that it doesn't actually work. The ajax request was firing earlier when it shouldn't have, but now in this form it wont fire on click of my anchor.

Comment: is the function getting invoked?

Comment: Yes the function is being invoked, at the top of the function I placed alert('hi'); and it would appear when the anchor was clicked, yet the AJAX would not load

Comment: how do you access the page in the browser?  What is in the url bar in the browser when you try to invoke the ajax?

Comment: The URL is - http://127.0.0.1/onlineshop/admin/?page=shop&id=product-list

Comment: is it http?  What Im getting at is you might have a same origin policy violation, so the browser isn't firing the ajax request at all.  Do you see anything in the server logs to indicate the request is even getting to the server?

Comment: try changing 127.0.0.1 to localhost

Comment: Ok, in the server access.log it doesn't show any GET requests, although it does for the other section of code I made that for some reason automatically loads the AJAX

Comment: You have a redundency. It says `($function())` and than within that `$(function())` you have a `$(document.ready()`. Try removing that original `$(function())`

Comment: `$(function()` and `$(document).ready()` are the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ajax will only work if it's the same domain. This means that if you execute jQuery from domain x to domain y, it won't work. This is for safety-reasons to prevent websites from loading from another website. Does your jQuery-ajax call work if you remove the `127.0.0.1` from your url?

Furthermore I guess you should add the click-function inside your `$(document).ready();` function, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a.fire').click(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "onlineshop/admin/scripts/test.php",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html){
            $("#holder").append(html);
        }
      });
   });
});
```

for testing purposes, you can also use the `complete` function inside your ajax and alert your data. firebug can be helpful too to find your problem :)

Comment: Firebug on google chrome seems to show that it is trying to GET the page according to the console, but it just refreshes the entire page on click

Comment: to prevent the page from refreshing (thats because its an a) you 'd better use a span and give it the according layout or make the click-function `return false;` :) giving the a an `href="#"` will work too :)

Comment: Don't know why I didn't use href="#", I think it's because last time it destroyed my current GET's, no idea why